# yii pdf not showing all records

Tags: php, pdf, yii, yii-extensions

I just installed [pdf extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf/)
It works fine but there is a small issue when I run it:

In admin view all records are shown (in my case 1013 records) but in the pdf only 207...

What could be the problem? I am really confused...Please help

This is the action:

```
public function actionTest(){
        $model = new Teilnehmer();

        $model->attributes = $_GET['Teilnehmer']; /* to execute the filters (if is the case) */
        $dataProvider  = $model->search();

        /* if yu want to ignore the pagination and retrieve all records */
        $dataProvider->pagination = false;
        $mPDF1 = Yii::app()->ePdf->mpdf();
        $mPDF1->WriteHTML($this->renderPartial('test', array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider), true));
        $mPDF1->Output();
}
```

where the view (test.php) has the same content as admin.php...

I can't figure where the problem is...

**EDIT**

Got it working...

I was missing:

```
$model->unsetAttributes();
```

after

```
$model = new Teilnehmer();
```